# Lithuanian language in subject of email?

Tags: php, wordpress, utf-8, utf-16

> į ė ę š ų ū  ž

I am working on Lithuanian language project in which I have to send email and subject in Lithuanian language.

I have used:

```
$headers = 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8';
```

Besides this I have also used :

```
charset=win-1257 along with utf-8
```

and such code

```
mail($to,"=?UTF-8?B?".base64_encode($subject)."?="."\r\n", $body, $headers);
```

here is my code:

```
$from = get_option('admin_email');
                    $headers =  array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
                    $subject ="į ė ę š ų ū atsiliepim? apie atliktus darbus";
                    $msg = $html_review;
                    wp_mail($email,"=?UTF-8?B?".base64_encode($subject)."?="."\r\n", $msg, $headers );
```

But getting no success, I am getting **?** in the subject text, Please let me know the suggestions so that I can display Lithuanian characters at the required position.

Comment: Saying "I'm using UTF-8" is fine, but you need to actually use it. Otherwise, it's like writing "This book is translated into Chinese" and expecting to get to translated automatically. But the best tip you can get is: don't format mail yourself; use a third-party library like Swift Mailer or PhpMailer. Otherwise, t's impossible to get it right.

Comment: What happens if you simply try putting English characters in the subject. Do you still get a ? or does it read fine?

Comment: In case of english it is going good.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I have used $headers = 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8'; and mail($to,"=?UTF-8?B?".base64_encode($subject)."?="."\r\n", $body, $headers);

Comment: What is your email client? Are you using a web-based one or Outlook? or other?

Answer (score 0):

Try using Quoted-Printable instead of binary, it might be better supported:

```
mail($to,"=?UTF-8?Q?".quoted_printable_encode($subject)."?="."\r\n", $body, $headers);
```

(Notice the `Q`in `"=?UTF-8?Q?"`.)

It will convert non-ASCII characters to something like

```
C4=AF =C4=97 =C4=99 =C5=A1 =C5=B3 =C5=AB atsiliepim? apie atliktus darbus
```